# Wrong answer in ProjectEuler incesption?

Tags: python

The goal of the code is to find the sum of all multiples of 3 and 5 under 1000 (natural numbers, so starting from 1).

My code:

```
sum_of_3 = 0
sum_of_5 = 0

for a in range (0, 1000, 3):
    sum_of_3 += a
print(sum_of_3)
Output: 166833

for b in range (0, 1000, 5)
    sum_of_5 += b
print (sum_of_5)
Output: 99500

total_sum = sum_of_3 + sum_of_5
print (total_sum)
Output: 266333
```

My output is wrong. The correct code and output is:

```
nums = range (1, 1000)
sumofmultiples = 0
for i in nums:
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        sumofmultiples = i + sumofmultiples
print (sumofmultiples)
Output: 233168
```

Why am I getting a different answer?

Comment: Your code counts multiples of 15 twice.

Answer (score 0):

When doing the collection of numbers in two seperate calculation, you add some numbers twice.

Have a look at 15, ist will be added onec since its a multipe of 3 and again, since its a multiple of 5.

If you want to keep your coed, you should check in your second for loop, whether the number ist dividable by 3.

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating some value twice!
For Example
15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105 and so on...

In your first loop you add some value such as 15, 30, 45
Then in your next loop you again add them!

In the correct code you can see there is a "Logical OR" operator which adding 15, 30, 45.... only for once

I hope you get it now
Thank you.